# Reading in from a plist, but accepting only certain strings

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, plist

The goal is to have an array where all strings are of length n.

So at the moment what I have my code doing is reading in a plist (which is just 250,000 strings) into an array, and then iterating over the array in order to find which ones are/aren't of length n.  Of course, for the sake of efficiency, I'd prefer being able to read in from the plist STRING BY STRING so, as I'm reading in, I may the length then before inserting into the array.  I'm just starting to learn objective-c, but I was struggling to Google around for a solution =P

EDIT: Well I just found out I can find much more documentation typing property list rather than plist into google :) so I may be able to figure this out myself

Comment: That is good if you found out your self. It is appreciated if you post your solution as answer or accept other's.

Comment: Current assumption after reading documentation is that there is no method of parsing specifically -- you basically read in the entire file, and then do stuff from there (as opposed to say in C where you could read line by line / char by char with various fget).  Thus, the method proposed below by NeverBe seems good enough to me -- I no longer have to iterate over it twice, since I am storing the lengths as I read through; an upgrade over the repetitive looping of my original

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse plist into tree (NSMutableDictionary). Dict will have keys with name of string length.

for example

```
NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSString *str in [plistDict allObjects]) {

    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [str length]];

    NSMutableArray *array = [result objectForKey:key];
    if (!array) {
        array = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    [array addObject:str];
    [result setObject:array forKey:key];
}
```

than you can access array with needed strings length

```
NSArray *string4Lenght = [result objectForKey:@"4"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't provide an API for incrementally parsing a plist.

If you store your plist in XML format, you could use `NSXMLParser` to parse it.  The schema is pretty simple and somewhat described in the [*Property List Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html).

If you want to incrementally parse the binary format, you're going to have to do more work.  There's no official documentation for the format.  Apple's source code for reading and writing the format is open source ([`CFBinaryPList.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635.19/CFBinaryPList.c)) and there are some useful comments along with the actual code.

If you really need to do it incrementally, I suggest going the XML route.  If you do, you might want to subclass `NSInputStream` to be able to read from a gzip or bzip2 file and decompress on the fly.